# I want to sum from two tables then substrate both the value to get revenue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to sum (Expense Amount) from Expense Table and (Order Amount) from Order Table By Date Then Substrate both the value to get revenue

```
Table 'Expenses'
Fields: expense_amount | expense_date
Data:   1000 | 2018-11-17
        1500 | 2018-11-17
        22 | 2018-11-18

Table 'Order'
Fields: order_amount | order_date
Data:   25000 | 2018-11-17
        10000 | 2018-11-17
        8000  | 2018-11-18
```

All i want is to total (expense_amount) AND (order_amount) by date
then subtract both the value to get revenue

FOR SINGLE table it use this code but

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST["date"]))
  {
  if($_POST["date"] != '')
  {
    $query = "SELECT sum(sub_total) AS total_order_value FROM tbl_order     
    tbl_order.order_customer_id
    WHERE order_date = '".$_POST["date"]."'";
   }
  else
  {
    $query = "SELECT sum(sub_total) AS total_order_value FROM tbl_order";
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "Rs. ";
    echo number_format($row['total_order_value'],2);
  }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use a join of two separate subqueries which find the sums of orders and expenses separately using aggregation by date.  Then, for each date, we can find the revenue.

```
SELECT
    t1.order_date,
    t1.order_sum - t2.expense_sum AS revenue
FROM
(
    SELECT order_date, SUM(order_amount) AS order_sum
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY order_date
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT expense_date, SUM(expense_amount) AS expense_sum
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY expense_date
) t2
    ON t1.order_date = t2.expense_date;
```

This answer assumes that a given date would always have an order and expense amount.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dte, sum(expense_amount) as expense_amount,
       sum(order_amount) as order_amount,
       sum(expense_amount) - sum(order_amount) as net
from ((select expense_date as dte, expense_amount, 0 as order_amount
       from expenses
      ) union all
      (select order_date as dte, 0 as expense_amount, order_amount
       from expenses
      ) 
     ) oe
group by dte;
```